# Fit background color to special characters

Tags: ios, swift

With following code, I change background color of a text. If the text does not have a special character like € or emoji, background color fits the background of the text. Do you have any idea what to do with these character to center vertically in background.

```
    mainLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    mainLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    mainLabel.sizeToFit()
    mainLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.090, green: 0.090, blue: 0.090, alpha: 0.8)
    mainLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Bauhaus", size: 14)
    mainLabel.textColor = UIColor(white:1, alpha:1)
    mainLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    mainLabel.baselineAdjustment = .AlignCenters
```

[image: this is okay]

[image: emoji problem]

[image: euro sign problem]

Comment: Are you using auto layout to position the label?

Comment: Are you trying to vertically center your label or the text within a label?

Comment: No, I don't use autolayout.  And, for the other question, I need to vertically center text in label.  Or, background color needs to be fit.